# Can I print directly onto the bed plate? (Ender 3 Pro)

Tags: creality-ender-3, bed

I just got an Ender 3 Pro at the beginning of the week and have been printing a lot. I creased the magnetic plate cover, not realizing how it would hold up to being bent. This led to uneven printing and nozzle issues, so I stopped using it.

Is there any problem with printing directly onto the platform itself, without a cover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've printed for several years direct onto the 3 mm heated bed of the Anet A8 I used; worked perfectly! I did use a specific 3D print spray for adhesion, see e.g. [this answer](/a/6861) on "[Should you use hairspray on a metal bed 3D printer?](/q/3710/)".

Comment: I'm super new to this, so just for clarification- The overlay that came with the printer and the glass bed upgrades are used for adhesion and removal purposes, but if I spray hair spray onto the original bed then I can print on it? What if I don't have hair spray? I'm using PLA.

Comment: Worked great! Tyvm. If you could still please clarify the purpose of the overlays (magnetic, glass, PEI, etc.), I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @Shades The magnetic bed is flexible, so you can bend to pop the print of. Glass and Buildtak are used for adhesion without the need to use a glue or spray, but sometimes, they also benefit from an additional adhesive. PEI fuses with PETG, so that didn't work well for me.